# Parallax изображение с помощью angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parallax

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь написать модуль, который будет содержать сервис и директиву (директива будет обращаться к сервису за значением), позволяющие применять paralax эффект к различным блокам, в моем случае к изображениям. Моя логика такова, есть сервис, который при включении отработает 1 раз и зарегистрирует событие window на scroll и будет записывать его в переменную, которую нужно видеть глобально в сервисе, и есть директива, которая постоянно применяет к элементу свойство translate. Но чувствую я что что-то делаю очень неправильно, + где-то ошибся и никак не могу заставить директиву видеть значение a сервиса. Выглядит это все так:

```
      angular.module("paralaxServices", []).service("mainParalaxService", paralax).directive("eParalaxable", paralaxable);

function paralax($window) {
    var service = {
        currentWindowPosition: 10
    }
    angular.element($window).on("scroll", setCurrentWindowPosition);
    return service;
};

function setCurrentWindowPosition(event) {
    currentWindowPosition = this.pageYOffset;
}

function paralaxable(mainParalaxService) {
    var directive = {
        restrict: "A",
        link: link
    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.css("transform", "translate(0%, " + mainParalaxService.currentWindowPosition + "%");
    }
}
```

На view все выглядит так:

```
<body ng-controller="mainController"> <!--этот контроллер, как и ng-app объявлены в другом модуле, который использует paralaxServices. первый и 3й див просто для отступов-->
<div  style="width: 100%; height: 100px; background-color:black"></div>
<div e-paralaxable class="container-for-paralax-image">

</div>
<div class="container-for-paralax-image2">

</div>
```

Помогите пожалуйста понять, что я делаю не так, и правильный ли я использую подход?

Comment: Проблему с видимостью решил(забыл сделать return сервиса), но все равно до сих пор обновление у директивы не происходит, при скролле

Answer (score 2, accepted):

функция `link` вызывается только при инициализации элемента, и лишь тогда она получает значение из сервиса. Вам надо придумать по каком "каналу" сервис будет оповещать директиву о изменившемся оффсете

Например, можно воспользоваться шаблоном [наблюдатель](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Внутри сервиса сделать что то вроде

```
var callbacks = [];
function subscribe( callback ) {
   callbacks.push( callback );
}

function notify() {
   callbacks.forEach( function(cb){
       cb( this.service.currentWindowPosition );
   });
}

function setCurrentWindowPosition(event) {
   this.service.currentWindowPosition = this.pageYOffset;

}

//TODO логика удаления подписчика
```

Внутри директивы

```
function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    mainParalaxService.subscribe( function(newOffset) { 
         element.css("transform", "translate(0%, " + newOffset + "%");
    });
}
```

Comment: Черт возмьми :), точно! я совсем забыл про событийное программирование, спасибо вам огромное!